# Google Play Permissions for Foreground Services violation for app targets Android 14

Tags: android, google-play, foreground-service, android-14, policy-violation

My app is a file downloader app. I have created a downloader service and use the foreground type "specialUse" to start foreground service. But after I submit the app, it is approved with an issue of "Policy Violation" for the foreground type. I have changed the app to use WorkManager long worker as foreground service, but it still need to start as foreground and specify a foreground type as stated here [WorkManager long worker](https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/background-tasks/persistent/how-to/long-running#foreground-service-type).

I also declared in the manifest file and in the Google Play console about the use of the foreground service:

```
    <service
        android:name="androidx.work.impl.foreground.SystemForegroundService"
        android:foregroundServiceType="specialUse"
        tools:node="merge" >
        <property android:name="android.app.PROPERTY_SPECIAL_USE_FGS_SUBTYPE"
            android:value="Use to run WorkManager's long worker to download large files."/>
    </service>
```

I submitted a new update but it is still approved with issue "Policy Violation". Here are the issues from the console:

1.

> Permissions for Foreground Services: Functionality is not initiated by or perceptible to the user

> We found that one or more of the declared use cases is not compliant with how foreground service permission is allowed to be used. Specifically, the user is not made aware of functionality requiring permission when active.

2. 

> Permissions for Foreground Services: Permission use is either not declared or incorrectly declared

> We found that one or more of the use cases utilizing the foreground service permission in your app has either been incorrectly submitted or is missing from your Console declaration.
> You have incorrectly declared your Special Use - Other functionality under the wrong FGS type.

3. 

> Permissions for Foreground Services: Service interruption or deferment of functionality does not have material user impact

> We found that one or more of the declared use cases is not compliant with how foreground service permission is allowed to be used. Specifically, the declared use case(s) can be interrupted or deferred by the system without creating a negative user experience.
> Your app is using foreground service to Special Use - Other when it is not required to do so.

I don't know what I am doing wrong and how to fix it. Is there anyone has the same issues knows how to fix them, please help!

Comment: Why are you putting special use there? What is special on downloading? Its just data synchronizing. Use that.